# getLatitude() , getLongitude() returns wrong latitude and longitude values

Tags: android, dictionary, geolocation

This is the code i use to find my current location but it is not pointing the location accurately, it returns a location as 9.920473,78.102423 instead of  9.909076, 78.100758

I could not figure it out where i am going wrong , please help me with suggestions.

```
   try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        }
        else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            if (isNetworkEnabled)   {
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                        Log.e("latitude", ""+latitude);
                        Log.e("longitude", ""+longitude);
                    }
                }
                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();                      
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                            Log.e("latitude", ""+latitude);
                            Log.e("longitude", ""+longitude);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you zoomed-in enough ? Its remote to assume that your gps is returning incorrect values.

Comment: Note that you are logging both network and gps locations - maybe you should indicate in the log which the user is seeing? Also, why test on both? If gps, you don't care about network, else if network - your granularity will not be good.

Comment: Zoomed-in enough ? sorry i could not get it @Siddharth , could u please explain . . .

Comment: If you are zoomed out, you will not be able to accurately pin point the location and identify if the gps returnedis correct or not. Right ?

Comment: to answer the title : no, it doesn't. you are interpreting it wrong

Comment: Remove the part you check isNetworkEnabled, it might be using network provider instead of gps provider.

Comment: But when i block that isNetworkEnabled codes , i am getting Lat and lon value as 0.0 and 0.0 . Anything wrong with my GPS code ?

Comment: location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER); returns null . . . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Network Provider first, which is not very accurate. If you get a location fix from Network your code wont use GPS location. In this case, this much variation in the location is to be expected. If you need exact location, use GPS Provider.

Comment: But my GPS code returns null in locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);    and i could not find where i am going wrong .

Comment: In this case, use the last known location from NETWORK_PROVIDER initially but later when your app receives a more accurate location from GPS_PROVIDER, use it instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code:

```
              public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
          if (location != null) {
            GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(
                (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6), 
                (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                "Latitude: " + location.getLatitude() + 
                " Longitude: " + location.getLongitude(), 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

}

Comment: And what it will do?